# Pages in another language

Tags: css, html

I am trying to translate this page of my theme to Portuguese, but I can not find where is the files to translate.

Link: http://novine.com.br.siteseguro.ws/lojakazola/lounge/
Text: (by admin. Posted on 08/11/2014)

I believe this is not the theme, but the wordpress. Maybe because it is in the English language. If so, would not want to have to redo everything again only because of this page in English, and I believe that if I replace all wordpress files for Portuguese wordpress, it will not work anymore.

Does anyone know WHAT can I do?

Comment: If the text is being generated by WordPress, then you need to set the language to Portuguese. http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Language_and_Language_Directory

Comment: Have you tried simply updating your wp-config.php? Change `define('WPLANG', '');` to `define('WPLANG','pt_BR');`? If that doesn't achieve what you're looking for, maybe show us a section of your templates loop so we can look into alternatives.

Comment: I downloaded the zip of wordpress Portuguese of my wordpress version, put the "languages" folder that is in wp-content and put this code in wp-config.php `define( 'WPLANG', 'pt_BR' );
define( 'WP_LANG_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . 'wp-content/languages' );` and still have not changed anything.